# I know that happens-before does not imply happening before, can the code "A = B + 1; B = 1;" produce the result "A == 2 and B == 1"?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

In [this article](https://preshing.com/20130702/the-happens-before-relation/), the author mentions that "Happens-Before Does Not Imply Happening Before" and he shows an example to explain.

```
int A = 0;
int B = 0;

void foo()
{
    A = B + 1;              // (1)
    B = 1;                  // (2)
}
```

He says that (2) can actually happen before (1), My question is that what will be the value of A if (2) actually happen before (1), 1 or 2?

Comment: "*He says that (2) can actually happen before (1)*" - that's incorrect. The order of evaluation would change the outcome of the operations, thus reordering it by the compiler is prohibited. By the way - which article?

Comment: It will always be a==1, b==1. If a reordering happens, it's because it won't effect the answer. And he seems to talking about C++ in that article, although tries to make it language agnostic.

Comment: @Fureeish I have edited the description, you can click [this article](https://preshing.com/20130702/the-happens-before-relation/) to read that article.

Comment: The article explains why the result is still as it must be.

Comment: You tagged this question with "multithreading" and with "concurrency", but your example does not show any communication between threads. Within any _single_ thread, everything that happens must be consistent with the _program order_ of the statements that you wrote. Therefore, the function that calls `foo()` when A and B both equal zero _must_ see both A and B equal to 1 after `foo()` returns.

Comment: "Happens before" rules only describe what happens when one thread observes actions that are taken by some other thread. If some other thread prints A and B, while `foo()` is being called, it is possible for the other thread to print A==0 and B==1. In the thread that calls `foo()`, the assignment to A "happens before" the assignment to B, but nothing in your example would transfer that "happens before" relationship to any other thread.  The other thread must eventually see A==1 and B==1, but it could see those two assignments happen in either order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` and `B` are locations in memory. However the operation `B+1` does not happen in memory, it happens in the CPU. Specifically, the author is describing these two operations.

*`A = B + 1` (1)*

- A1 - The value in memory location `B` (`0`) is loaded into a CPU register
- A2 - The CPU register is incremented by `1`
- A3 - The value in the CPU register (`1`) is written to memory location `A`

*`B = 1` (2)*

- B1 - The value `1` is written to memory location `B`

*Happens-Before* requires that the read of `B` (step A1) happens before the write of `B` (step B1). However, the rest of the operations have no interdependence and can be reordered without affecting the result. Any of these sequences will produce the same outcome

- A1, B1, A2, A3
- A1, A2, B1, A3
- A1, A2, A3, B1

Answer (score 0):

The author seems to mean that order of execution doesn't have to match the order in which the statements are written.

Reordering of program actions can be performed by either the JVM or the CPU, both of which you have little control of.

The point is that in Java you can only rely on what the Java Memory Model guarantees, and not the order of statements in your source code.